# Select single value from one column and list of values from another column from different table

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Table 1:

```
productId
productName
```

Table 2:

```
Id
productId - foregn key with references to table 1
productLoacation
```

I want toselect productId,productName and list of productLoactions?

I have tried as below,

```
 var mailAddress = from tb1 in DbContext.table1
               join tb2 in DbContext.Table2 on tb1.productId equals tb2.productId
               where tb1.table1== 1234
               select { tb1.productName, tb2.productLoacation.ToList()};
```

How can I achive in a single query without creating a entity?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query (I suppose, that `table1` field is unique identifier):

```
var mailAddress = (from tb1 in DbContext.table1
                   where tb1.table1 == 1234
                   join tb2 in DbContext.Table2 on tb1.productId equals tb2.productId
                   group tb2 by new { tb1.productId, tb1.productName } into sub
                   select new {
                       sub.Key.productId,
                       sub.Key.productName,
                       productLocations = sub.ToList()
                  }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Another way is to use `Future` from [EntityFramework.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended) library:

```
var fromTable1Query = DbContext.table1.Where(x => x.table1 == 1234).Future();

var fromTable2Query = (from tb1 in DbContext.table1
                       where tb1.table1 == 1234
                       join tb2 in DbContext.table2 on tb1.productId equals tb2.productId
                       select tb2).Future();

mailAddress.product = fromTable1Query.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
mailAddress.productLocations = fromTable2Query.ToList();
```

These two queries will be executed together in exactly **one** trip to database.